# How to save frames to a video file e.g. mp4 using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession

I am using a `AVCaptureSession` and `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` to capture video frames from the back camera of my iphone.  I would like to save these frames to a file.  How do I do this in swift?  I see that there is a delegate method that is returning the frames.

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    // Here you collect each frame and process it
}
```